# c#-doc-viewer for VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

c# offers a nice way to document your c#-code. But I don´t find any nice viewer. I search something like the java-doc-viewer in eclipse. This viewer allows you to browse in the java-doc just by moving your mouse over eg. a class-name.

Does someone know a good extension for Visual Studio 2010 that contains such a viewer?

I have the "Productivity Power Tools"-Extension installed. But it hasn´t a real doc-viewer either.

Edit:
Here is a picture of what I search:
[image: Example of java-doc-vieser in Eclipse]

And this is the best I can find for VisualStudio:
[image: Doc-Viewer of Productivity Power Tools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try using [CR_Documentor](https://github.com/tillig/CR_Documentor), if you don't mind installing Code Rush (alone for that purpose; you only need the free "DXCore" actually, checkout the project's homepage for more information).

Note that this tool doesn't require a prior generation of the documentation using tools like Sandcastle. It works by simply placing your cursor in a API comment block, e.g. that of a method.

Obviously, this has some drawbacks, for example, links to other items (e.g. `<see/>` or `<seealso>` will be rendered as a link, but don't work as such).

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I was using it once, way back [when it was still maintained by the original author Lutz Roeder](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LutzRoedersDocumentorUpdatedAsACodeRushPluginVisualStudioNETAddIn.aspx), and it did it's job well. I have not been using it since.

**Update**: You could also use ReSharper, which provides a "[Quick Documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Quick_Documentation.html)" feature.

Comment: The Quick Documentation of ReSharper looks quite good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built-in tool in VS for viewing the documentation of your code. You have to generate the documentation pages from the XML doc, using external tools.

**Free tools:**

- [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) is the most well known, it has a lot of features, but it doesn't seem to be maintained any more and it's quite difficult to use (although [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) makes it significantly easier, and is still maintained).
- [docu](http://docu.jagregory.com/) is simpler to use, but not specific to .NET
- [Monodoc](http://www.mono-project.com/Monodoc) (from the Mono project)

**Commercial tools:**

- [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html)
- [Document! X](http://www.innovasys.com/products/dx2011/overview.aspx?r=1)
- [Doc-O-Matic](http://www.doc-o-matic.com/features.html)
- [ForgeDoc](http://www.forgedoc.com/): this one is quite new and looks very promising: very lightweight, simple to use, fast, good-looking output... It's also much cheaper than the others above

Comment: You might want to add a hint, that some tools (e.g. VSdocman as it looks), don't actually require a prior generation of documentation to show it in Visual Studio (which is what the OP seems to be looking for).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NDoc` to build the API documentation and generate help files (typically HTML files)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc/

Comment: NDoc is more or less dead, or "stale" (the latest what's new update on their [homepage](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) is from 2005) - unfortunately, as some might say. Also, I doubt there ever was an "instant-viewer" for VS.